# Sort values for both str and int by ranking appearance in a string

Tags: python, string, list, sorting, integer

I have to sort keywords and values in a string.

This is my attempt:

```
import re
phrase='$1000 is the price of the car, it is 10 years old. And this sandwish cost me 10.34£'
list1 = (re.findall('\d*\.?\d+', phrase)) #this is to make a list that find all the ints in my phrase and sort them (1000, 10, 10.34)

list2= ['car', 'year', 'sandwish'] #this is to make a list of all the keywords in the phrase I need to find.

joinedlist = list1 + list2 #This is the combination of the 2 lists int and str that are in my sentence (the key elements)

filter1 = (sorted(joinedlist, key=phrase.find)) #This is to find all the key elements in my phrase and sort them by order of appearance.

print(filter1)
```

Unfortunately, in some cases, because the "sorted" function works by lexical sorting, integrals would be printed in the wrong order. This means that in some cases like this one, the output will be:

```
['1000', '10', 'car', 'year', 'sandwich', '10.34']
```

instead of:

```
['1000', 'car', '10', 'year', 'sandwich', '10.34']
```

as the car appears before 10 in the initial phrase.

Comment: The reason you get the output you see is that `1000` and `10` occur at the same place in `phrase` and so are first in `filter1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lexical sorting has nothing to do with it, because your sorting `key` is the position in the original phrase; all the sorting is done by numeric values (the indices returned by `find`).  The reason that the `'10'` is appearing "out of order" is that `phrase.find` returns the first occurrence of it, which is inside the `1000` part of the string!

Rather than breaking the sentence apart into two lists and then trying to reassemble them with a `sort`, why not just use a single regex that selects the different kinds of things you want to keep?  That way you don't need to re-sort them at all:

```
>>> re.findall('\d*\.?\d+|car|year|sandwish', phrase)
['1000', 'car', '10', 'year', 'sandwish', '10.34']
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `10` and `1000` each have the same value from Python's default string lookup. Both are found at the start of the string since `10` is a substring of `1000`.

You *can* implement a regex lookup into `phrase` to implement the method you are attempting by using `\b` word boundaries so that `10` only matches `10` in your string:

```
def finder(s):
    if m:=re.search(rf'\b{s}\b', phrase):
        return m.span()[0]
    elif m:=re.search(rf'\b{s}', phrase):
        return m.span()[0]
    return -1
```

Test it:

```
>>> sorted(joinedlist, key=finder)
['1000', 'car', '10', 'year', 'sandwish', '10.34']
```

It is easier if you turn `phrase` into a look up list of your keywords however. You will need some treatment for `year` as a keyword vs `years` in `phrase`; you can just use the regex `r'\d+\.\d+|\w+'` as a regex to find the words and then `str.startswith()` to test if it is close enough:

```
pl=re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+|\w+', phrase)

def finder2(s):
    try:                    # first try an exact match
        return pl.index(s)
    except ValueError:
        pass                # not found; now try .startswith()
    try:    
        return next(i for i,w in enumerate(pl) if w.startswith(s))  
    except StopIteration:
        return -1   

>>> sorted(joinedlist, key=finder2)
['1000', 'car', '10', 'year', 'sandwish', '10.34']
```